# Using xpath to confirm <h4> text with a <strong tag> in the middle

Tags: selenium, webdriver, java, xpath

I'm using the Java Selenium WebDriver implementation. I'm searching for a string literal in an  tag which has a  tag in the middle, i.e.

```
<h4>Some regular text <strong>followed by strong text</strong> followed by regular text</h4>
```

I'm able to create an xpath selector for the first 2/3 (i.e., through the end of the strong tag), but not for the rest:

```
By.xpath("//h4[contains(text(),'Some regular text ')]" +
            "/descendant::strong[contains(text(), 'followed by strong text')]"
```

But I cannot finish the xpath path selector. Perhaps matching the first two-thirds is sufficient, but I wanted to find out for my own edification / completeness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> //h4[contains(text(),'Some regular text ')]
> ```

You are starting correct, though the first part, `//h4[contains(text(),'Some regular text ')]`, looks for any `h4` at any depth, with among its immediate children a text node containing `Some regular text`. Meaning, if that text appears *after* the `strong` element, it will also match the `h4`.

> ```
> /descendant::strong[contains(text(), 'followed by strong text')]
> ```

You chose `descendant::`, which means it will search at any depth from `h4` for a `strong` element. If you had `<span><div><strong>...</strong></div></span>` it would also find it. If that's the intend, leave it as is. If not, and you want an immediate child, then use just `/strong[...]`.

Your XPath as a whole will select that `strong` element containing the text `followed by strong text`, with an ancestor `h4` as specified before.

> Perhaps matching the first two-thirds is sufficient

You say this is ⅔ of what you wanted to achieve. Do you mean you need to select the text node? In that case, append the expression with `/text()`.

Essentially, this XPath returns *something*, or *nothing*. It will return nothing if it can't find both texts the way you specified it. Otherwise it will return the `strong` element. If you just need to verify its existence, you are done.

> through the end of the strong tag

This is not quite right, but I understand the confusion. XPath does not see tags, it sees elements (or more generally: nodes), which is the whole of the opening tag and the closing tag, all its descendants, processing instructions, attributes and namespaces. As such, and as suggested, you can then query whatever is inside the `strong` *element*.

---

#### Update (selecting following sibling)

After your comment, I think the rules are as follows:

- Any `h4` with an immediate child `strong`
- Before `strong` contains text `X`
- Inside `strong`, contains text `Y`
- After `strong`, contains text `Z`

This can be written as:

```
//h4[text()[1][contains(., 'X')]]
    /strong
       [contains(., 'Y')]
       [following-sibling::text()[1][contains(., 'Z')]]
```

Written in such a way that it still returns the `strong` element. If you want the whole `h4` to be returned, write everything as a predicate of it (though for a boolean test whether this returns *anything*, this obviously won't matter):

```
//h4
    [text()[1][contains(., 'X')] 
        and text()[last()][contains(', 'Z')]]
    [strong[contains(., 'Y')]]
```

*(for illustration, it uses a slightly different approach for the third text match)*

Comment: Thanks for the response, specifically on demonstrating how to signal for an immediate child, which is what I did want. However the last part isn't clear. I want to include the text (still within the h4 node), i.e. <h4>first <strong> second </strong> third</h4>. I want to include the text 'third' in my xpath selector.

Comment: @douglas, I have updated with that in mind. Note, if you want an exact match, use `=` instead of `contains()`.